# Incorrect street short_name returned from JSON geocode call

Tags: json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I recently started having this problem on many streets in at least 2 different areas of our state.  For many streets - but not for all - the short_name is being returned as "STATE ROAD NNNN" instead of the common shortened name of the street.  For example:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=8000+Wynnview+Road,+Indian+Trail,+NC&sensor=false

Returns:

```
{
   "results" : [
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "8000",
           "short_name" : "8000",
           "types" : [ "street_number" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Wynnview Road",
           "short_name" : "State Rd 2326",
           "types" : [ "route" ]
        },
```

"State Rd 2326" does not mean anything to anyone.  I'm assuming this is some internal DOT name.  Instead, this should be returning "Wynnview Rd", just like it does for other street names.

What are my options to have this corrected?  As I said, this is happening for many streets in my area, and this is affecting an application we have that uses the short_name field.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Google has chosen to use the `short_name` field to denote the [State Road](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numbered_highways_in_the_United_States#State_highways_and_other_similar_systems) number. Because this is their service that they provide and own, your only option appears to be submitting a bug report here: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list

In this case, you're likely going to need to adjust your application to use the long_name field, and if necessary, use [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) to shorten or abbreviate the results where applicable.